# ggfortify::autoplot error on the cluster package: "Error: (converted from warning) partial match of 'cluster' to 'clustering'"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

I'm getting a cryptic error from `ggfortify::autoplot()` when trying to use *any* of the functions from the `cluster` package.

```
# load the environment
install.packages("ggplot2"); library(ggplot2)
install.packages("ggfortify"); library(ggfortify)
install.packages("cluster"); library(cluster)
```

Use the [example from the [Tag:ggfortify] vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html) for `cluster::pam`:

```
autoplot(cluster::pam(iris[-5], 3), frame = TRUE, frame.type = 'norm')
```

> Error: (converted from warning) partial match of 'cluster' to 'clustering'

I know that sometimes errors can be caused due to conflicts between packages, that is, two (or more) packages might have functions named similarly. However, I don't think this is the problem since I adapted the code from the vignette to specifically specify which package I wanted the function to come from with `cluster::pam` and I don't see any issues with `conflicts(detail=TRUE)`.

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build
>   9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html) LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  [2]
>   LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
>   [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    [5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html) stats     graphics  grDevices [4] utils
>   datasets  methods   [7] base
>
> other attached packages: [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html) ggfortify_0.4.5    [2] ggplot2_3.1.0
>   [3] cluster_2.0.7-1    [4] usethis_1.4.0.9000 [5] devtools_2.0.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html) Rcpp_1.0.0         [2]
>   compiler_3.5.2     [3] pillar_1.3.1       [4] plyr_1.8.4         [5]
>   bindr_0.1.1        [6] prettyunits_1.0.2  [7] remotes_2.0.2      [8]
>   tools_3.5.2        [9] testthat_2.0.1    [10] digest_0.6.18     [11]
>   pkgbuild_1.0.2    [12] pkgload_1.0.2     [13] memoise_1.1.0     [14]
>   tibble_1.4.2      [15] gtable_0.2.0      [16] pkgconfig_2.0.2   [17]
>   rlang_0.3.0.1     [18] cli_1.0.1         [19] rstudioapi_0.8    [20]
>   yaml_2.2.0        [21] bindrcpp_0.2.2    [22] gridExtra_2.3     [23]
>   stringr_1.3.1     [24] withr_2.1.2       [25] dplyr_0.7.8       [26]
>   desc_1.2.0        [27] fs_1.2.6          [28] tidyselect_0.2.5  [29]
>   rprojroot_1.3-2   [30] grid_3.5.2        [31] glue_1.3.0        [32]
>   R6_2.3.0          [33] processx_3.2.1    [34] sessioninfo_1.1.1 [35]
>   tidyr_0.8.2       [36] purrr_0.2.5       [37] callr_3.1.1       [38]
>   magrittr_1.5      [39] backports_1.1.3   [40] scales_1.0.0      [41]
>   ps_1.3.0          [42] assertthat_0.2.0  [43] colorspace_1.3-2  [44]
>   stringi_1.2.4     [45] lazyeval_0.2.1    [46] munsell_0.5.0     [47]
>   crayon_1.3.4

Comment: Works fine for me! Similar session info. Perhaps a restart might help?

Comment: Sadly a simple restart of R or the laptop did not solve this problem. *Rolls up sleeve* gonna have to do this the hard way...

Answer (score 1):

Deleted all of my libraries after uninstalling R 3.5.2 and RStudio 1.1.463. After reinstalling this issue was fixed